# pass Meteor user data to redux

Tags: meteor, react-native, redux

how to pass Meteor user data to redux, on initializing react-native app. 
Here is my code. I use tracker for subscribe for changes, but it works very strangely. It reacts for changes for only one time.
What is the best way to update the `Meteor.user()` info in redux store??

```
export const loadUser = () => dispatch => {
console.log('load user)')
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    console.log('datachanges user')
    const loginStatus = Meteor.loggingIn();
    dispatch({
        type: 'USER_LOGGING_IN',
        payload: loginStatus
    });
});

Tracker.autorun(() => {
    console.log('datachanges logins')
    const user = Meteor.user()
    dispatch({
        type: 'USER_DATA',
        payload: user,
    });
});
};
```